# Get data of last days ago in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get data of days ago.But I want that it start from 00:00

ViewsLog.where('created_at >= ?', 1.days.ago)

But it get data from the same time as from now.I want that it get data from 00:00:00

```
SELECT "views_logs".* FROM "views_logs" WHERE (created_at >= '2015-12-07 14:16:22.346497')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try some thing like

```
ViewsLog.where('created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago.to_datetime)
```

This will create SQL query exactly like

```
SELECT "views_logs".* FROM "views_logs"  WHERE (created_at >= '2015-12-07 00:00:00.000000')
```

Comment: `(Date.today - 1.day).to_datetime` can be simplified to `1.day.ago.to_datetime`

Answer (score 2):

`1.days.ago.beginning_of_day` or

`Time.now.beginning_of_day - 1.day`

readme more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-datetime